# Infinite sum of the golden ratio involving only itself - possible for other numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I just read about the golden ratio and the golden rectangle and then discovered in a depiction of such a rectangle with a logarithmic spiral inscribed in it, that the total area of the golden rectangle can be described as
$$a^2 \phi = a^2 + \frac{a^2}{\phi^2} + \frac{a^2}{\phi^4} +  \frac{a^2}{\phi^6} + \ldots $$
where $a$ is the side length of the biggest square inside the golden rectangle and $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

[image]

Dividing the above equation through $a^2$ leaves me with an infinite series that involves only fractions of powers of $\phi$ and adds up to $\phi$.

I then tried what would happen if instead of taking $\phi$ as the golden ratio I took it as another number $n$. For $n = 2$ and $n = 3$ I constructed a „golden rectangle“ with the respective ratios $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$. I did not get an infinite series that involves only fractions of powers of $n$ and where the sum of it is equal to $n$ for these (although for $n = 3$ the infinite series adds up to $1.5$, or $\frac{3}{2}$).

So my question is: Are there any other numbers that can be represented as the sum of such an infinite series?

Comment: @PeterForeman how do you get that $1 + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^4} + \ldots = \frac{1}{1 - x^2}?$

The infinite series does in fact converge to $\phi$. You can try it out with a calculator, or  should I add a proof to the question?

Comment: Sorry I applied the geometric sum formula incorrectly. You should have$$x=1+\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{x^4}+\dots=\frac1{1-\frac1{x^2}}=\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}$$but $x\ne0$ so the only solutions are from$$x=x^2-1\iff x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}2\iff x=\phi,-\frac1{\phi}$$Although the sum doesn't converge for $x=-1/\phi$ so $x=\phi$ is the only solution.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't know about that formula! That answers my question